# Select all possible string combinations from within a single field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Searching for this question I found references to cross join. BUt that only goes 2 wide. Suppose I have a single field `fruits` with values `apple`, `pear`, `banana` I could have (single string with spaces):

1. apple
2. apple pear
3. apple pear banana
4. apple banana
5. pear
6. banana
7. pear banana

I don't want doubles or triples e.g. `apple`, `apple`

How can I select all potential combinations from field `fruits` in this way?